# Raspberry Pi Not Working on certain HDMI monitor

Tags: raspberry-pi3, hdmi

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and a 7 inch HDMI Display monitor 800 by 480 resolution. When I connect the Raspberry Pi to the TV monitor by HDMI port, it works fine, but when I connect the Raspberry Pi to the 7 inch HDMI Display, the screen stays black. I have tried changing the Raspberry Pi screen resolution and multiple different settings, but nothing makes it work. Is there any way I can get this to work? Could I test to see if the monitor is even functional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently discovered that part of the HDMI monitor depends on the touch screen USB and Micro USB being in as well as an HDMI port. Once I plugged this in, it received enough power to show the something on the screen.